What does Density really mean?
We say that density is mass per unit volume and if an object has high density that means it has more amount of matter contained per unit volume but as we know mass is not the amount of matter contained in a body rather the measurement of inertia. So how can the definition of mass mean amount of matter when talking about density but measurement of inertia when talking about any other instance?

There is no distinction between gravitational and inertial mass therefore, mass is a measure of how much matter there is. In this sense, density is a measure of how compressed or rarefied the matter in question is, thus a cubic meter of iron contains much more matter than a cubic meter of helium at room temperature.
